# Javascript – creating instances of the same object and factoring out common code

Tags: javascript, html, oop, refactoring

So, I am working on this website and have created multiple charts (which are all very similar, except for the data that I am plotting in each of them).  Currently, I have javascript files, one for each of the charts, which contain mostly the same functions and variables (height, width, etc.) with the only difference being where the data is coming from and some other things.

However, I want to be able to include several of these javascript files into a webpage (so that all the charts show up together).  But this will not work because there are common variable and function names in the javascript files (since they're pretty much the same scripts, as mentioned above).  **What would be the best way to avoid this conflict so that I can include multiple charts in the same webpage?**

I am thinking it would be a good idea to factor out the common code and maybe have it so that each chart is an instance of some object.  If each chart is an instance of, let’s say, a ‘Chart’ object, would that allow me to include multiple html/javascript files in the same webpage?

Apologies if the question is vague/unclear or has already been asked!

EDIT:
So I will post the specific code a little later, but my javascript files are essentially like this:

```
chartA.js:
var height = 10;
var width = 40;
var colors = ...;
var dataSource = chartA_data.json
function addDataToChart(source) {
    //this adds the data in source to the html for chartA
}
addDataToChart(dataSource);

 chartB.js:
 var height = 10;
 var width = 40;
 var colors = ...;
 var dataSource = chartB_data.json 
 function addDataToChart(source) {
    //this adds the data in source to the html for chartA
}
 addDataToChart(dataSource);
```

So, basically, the two js files are the same except for the dataSource variable.  Would creating a chart object, with chartA and chartB as instances of the object, work?

Comment: There isn't much to say regarding what you ask if you don't share some code. Anyway, in order to avoid the conflict you mention, you should consider using the module pattern. Check this post if you don't know about it: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: be clear with your codes & then ask your question...

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will take a look at it now. I have also added a general idea of what my files look like

Comment: Yes, you really should use objects with properties, instead of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Would creating a chart object, with chartA and chartB as instances of
>   the object, work?

It's definitely one way of doing it. The example is overly simplistic, but you will get the idea:

```js
function Chart(args) {
  this._name = args.name;
  this._height = args.height;
  this._width = args.width;
  this._dataFetchingStrategy = args.dataFetchingStrategy;
  
  //You may not want to call the rendering process immediately, but
  //it was simpler for the example
  this._render();
}

Chart.prototype = {
  constructor: Chart,
  
  _render: function () {
    var el = this.el = document.createElement('div');
    el.classList.add('chart');
    el.style.height = this._height + 'px';
    el.style.width = this._width + 'px';
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this._name));
    this._contentEl = el.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    this.refresh();
  },
  
  refresh: function () {
    this._dataFetchingStrategy(function (data) {
      this._contentEl.innerHTML = data;
    }.bind(this));
  }
};


[
  new Chart({ 
    name: 'Chart A', 
    height: 100, 
    width: 100,
    dataFetchingStrategy: function (cb) {
      cb('Data for chart A');
    }
  }),
  
  new Chart({ 
    name: 'Chart B', 
    height: 150, 
    width: 200,
    dataFetchingStrategy: function (cb) {
      setTimeout(cb.bind(null, 'Data for chart B'), 1500);
    }
  })
].forEach(function (chart) {
  document.body.appendChild(chart.el);
});
```

```css
.chart {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```